# Test using Nock in a scheduleJob

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, nock, node-schedule

I'm getting a problem with test the http request in a scheduleJob node. Well, I've changed the crontime to run every second as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117058/test-node-schedule-with-sinon-faketimers) for easier testing. The problem is, I don't think the Nock that I created to test the http request works fine. Because when I do the console.log('res : ', res); it either returns undefined or does not print anything as shown here : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INJLi.png).
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Index.js

```
schedule = require('node-schedule'),
var dateObj = Date.now();
dateObj += 1000;
schedule.scheduleJob(new Date(dateObj), function(){
console.log("get's here..");
const url_req = "https://git.ecommchannels.com/api/v4/users";
request.get(
    {
     url_req,
     qs : {private_token: token, per_page: 10}
}, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('res : ', res);
    var total = res.headers['x-total-pages']
    console.log('res.headers', res.headers);
    for( i=1; i<=total; i++ ){
        url_req2 = "https://git.ecommchannels.com/api/v4/users";
        request.get({
            url_req2,
            qs: {private_token : token, per_page : 10, page : i},
            json : true
        },
            (err2, res2, body2) => {
            body2.forEach(element => {
                if(condition){
                    //do something
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

});

The unit test:

```
describe('test the http request', function(){
var clock;
const nockingGit = () =>{
    nock('https://git.ecommchannels.com')
    .defaultReplyHeaders({
        'x-total-pages': 10
    })
    .get('/api/v4/users')
    .query({private_token: 'blabla', per_page: 10})
    .reply(201, {});
}
beforeEach(function () {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(function () {
  clock.restore();
});
it('test the http request', (done)=>{
    nockingGit();
    setTimeout(function(){
        done();
    },3000)
    clock.tick(3000);
})
```

})

---

## edited

index.js

```
schedule.scheduleJob(new Date(dateObj), function(){
  var now = new Date();
  flag = true;
  console.log(now.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta'}));
  console.log("get's here..");
  gitReq();
});

function gitReq(){
const url_req = "https://git.ecommchannels.com/api/v4/users";
request.get(
  {
     url_req,
     qs : {private_token: token, per_page: 10}
  }, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('res : ', res);
    var total = res.headers['x-total-pages']
    // console.log('res.headers', res.headers);
    for( i=1; i<=total; i++ ){
        url_req2 = "https://git.ecommchannels.com/api/v4/users";
        request.get({
            url_req2,
            qs: {private_token : token, per_page : 10, page : i},
            json : true
        },
            // "https://git.ecommchannels.com/api/v4/users?private_token=" + token + "&per_page=10&page=" + i, { json: true }, 
            (err2, res2, body2) => {
            body2.forEach(element => {
                if(condition){
                    //do something
                }
            })
        })
    }
  })
}
```

Unit Test

*check whether the `gitReq()` is called - using `sinon.spy` (but I'm not sure whether the implementation is correct)

```
const sendReq = {
gitReq: ()=>{}}

describe('test the schedule job', function(){
var clock;
beforeEach(function () {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(function () {
  clock.restore();
});
it('should call the gitReq once', (done)=>{
    let gitReq = sinon.spy(sendReq,"gitReq");
    sendReq.gitReq();
    console.log("callcount : ", gitReq.callCount);
    gitReq.restore();
    setTimeout(function(){
        expect(gitReq.calledOnce).to.be.true;
        done();
    },3000)
    clock.tick(3000);
})})
```

*test the http request using `nock` that still returns undefined for the `res`.

```
describe('test the http request', function(){
  const nockingGit = () =>{
    nock('https://git.ecommchannels.com')
      .defaultReplyHeaders({
        'x-total-pages': 10
      })
      .get('/api/v4/users')
      .query({private_token: 'UKz2cZP9CHz2DT_o2-s9', per_page: 10})
      .reply(304, {});
  }
  it('test the http request', function(){
    nockingGit();
    _import.gitReq()
  })
})
```

*here's the [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVceI.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what `request` is an instance of in index.js? Is is just an import of the `request` lib? Also, your test never actually calls the service.

Comment: ahhh I see why the service isn't being called. I would recommend against that approach. Pull out the function being passed to `scheduleJob` and test it in isolation.

Comment: I've edited the code in the question as you suggested.. but I'm not sure. please have a look. It still has the issue.

Comment: Have you looked at what the value of `err` is in your first requests callback?

Comment: the error happens if connection timeout

Comment: I've solved the issue.. the res is no longer undefined